# How can the microphone work for speakerphone calls but not regular calls?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, microphone, speakerphone

My Droid Turbo (Android v.4.4.4) has developed a problem. When I make calls nobody can hear me, but as soon as I hit the speakerphone button everything is fine. I'd take the phone back to Verizon for a replacement, but it's the same microphone in both situations, right? So how could it be a hardware problem? Is there maybe a volume setting somewhere I need to tweak?

Answer (score 2):

Lots of phones have more than one microphone on them. I know for a fact that my Oneplus One has three, and I think your phone has four. If that's the case then it could be a hardware issue.  before taking it back do a full reset and see whether that helps. At least then that eliminates the possibility of a software error.

Answer (score 0):

My LG G5 running Android version 8 developed the same problem earlier this year but the cause ended up being the case I was using because I had no problem while the computer was not in a case and the two cases I bought since then, an Otter Box Defender and Otter Box Symmetry, do not seem to cause a problem for the microphone but the transparent plastic case from Amazon that I was using from 2022 to earlier in 2023 seems to have begun blocking the sound from the microphone during handset calls but not speakerphone calls.  Was the original poster using a case?  If yes then did they try without the case?

Comment: The critical bit is that there are at least 2 microphones. And one or more of them are getting blocked by the case.